# Wrong R Shiny dashboardBody tabtable position

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, sodium

I am trying to add log in options for my Shiny app, and currently trying out the solution here: https://www.r-craft.org/r-news/how-to-build-login-page-in-r-shiny-app/

I modified the code a little bit (marked with comments below), but run into issues, such as the tabsetPanel position is very off to the right, and the html code in dashboardBody is not functioning for sidebar background color and font color.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(sodium)

# Main login screen
loginpage <- div(id = "loginpage", style = "width: 500px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;",
                 wellPanel(
                   tags$h2("LOG IN", class = "text-center", style = "padding-top: 0;color:#333; font-weight:600;"),
                   textInput("userName", placeholder="Username", label = tagList(icon("user"), "Username")),
                   passwordInput("passwd", placeholder="Password", label = tagList(icon("unlock-alt"), "Password")),
                   br(),
                   div(
                     style = "text-align: center;",
                     actionButton("login", "SIGN IN", style = "color: white; background-color:#3c8dbc;
                                 padding: 10px 15px; width: 150px; cursor: pointer;
                                 font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600;"),
                     shinyjs::hidden(
                       div(id = "nomatch",
                           tags$p("Oops! Incorrect username or password!",
                                  style = "color: red; font-weight: 600; 
                                            padding-top: 5px;font-size:16px;", 
                                  class = "text-center"))),
                     br(),
                     br(),
                     tags$code("Username: myuser  Password: mypass"),
                     br(),
                     tags$code("Username: myuser1  Password: mypass1")
                   ))
)

credentials = data.frame(
  username_id = c("myuser", "myuser1"),
  passod   = sapply(c("mypass", "mypass1"),password_store),
  permission  = c("basic", "advanced"), 
  stringsAsFactors = F
)


header <- dashboardHeader(

#------Header changes starts (this change seems to work fine)
  title = h3(HTML("ABC")), 

  tags$li(class = "dropdown",
          tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 100px}")
  ),

  #User
  tags$li(
    class = "dropdown",
    a(tags$img
      (
        height = "70px",
        width = "45px",
        src="Pic.png",
        style = "margin-top:50px cursor: pointer;"
      )
    )
  ),

  #Logo
  tags$li(
    class = "dropdown",
    a(tags$img
      (
        height = "70px",
        width = "200px",
        src="Pic.png",
        style = "margin-left:-10px; cursor: pointer;"
      )
    )
  ),

  tags$li(
    class = "dropdown",
    a(tags$img
      (
        height = "95px",
        width = "948.7px",
        src="Pic.png",
        style = "margin:-1em"
      )
    )
  )
)

#------Header changes ends (this change seems to work fine)

#------Changes starts
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")) 
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))
#------Changes ends
ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "blue")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  login = FALSE
  USER <- reactiveValues(login = login)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$login == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$login)) {
        if (input$login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          if(length(which(credentials$username_id==Username))==1) { 
            pasmatch  <- credentials["passod"][which(credentials$username_id==Username),]
            pasverify <- password_verify(pasmatch, Password)
            if(pasverify) {
              USER$login <- TRUE
            } else {
              shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
              shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
            }
          } else {
            shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade")
            shinyjs::delay(3000, shinyjs::toggle(id = "nomatch", anim = TRUE, time = 1, animType = "fade"))
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })

  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    if (USER$login == TRUE ){

#------Change starts (this change seems to work fine)
      dashboardSidebar(
        hr(),
        hr(),
        selectInput('name', 'Name', c("Andrew"), multiple = FALSE , selected = "Andrew")
      )
    }
  })

#------Change ends (this change seems to work fine)

  output$body <- renderUI({
    if (USER$login == TRUE ) {

#------Change starts (this part is not working)
      dashboardBody(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
          '.skin-black .main-sidebar {
          background-color: #15317E;}')
        )),

        tags$style(type = "text/css", "a{color: #15317E;}"),

        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Tab",
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel(
                       "SubpannelA",
                       img(
                         height = "450px",
                         width = "1250px",
                         src="Image.png",
                         align = "middle")
                     ),
                     tabPanel(
                       "SubpannelB",
                       fluidRow(column(width = 6))
                     ),
                     tabPanel(
                       "SubpannelC",
                       fluidRow(column(width = 6))
                     )
                   )
        )))

#------Change ends
    }
    else {
      loginpage
    }
  })

  output$results <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                                   searching = FALSE))
  })

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
)
```

Any advice would be appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: Can you also include others parts of your code to make it reproducible, so we can run the app just by copying the code snippet?

Comment: Thank you @yifyan for your comment - I have attached the full code.

Comment: I think the positioning problems are caused by calling ```dashboardBody()``` in the UI and the server at the same time, same with ```dashboardSidebar```

Comment: @nogbad I can't agree more - I am not skillful enough to edit the original code to make it not calling dashboardBody() twice though. Any quick thoughts?